# M1 Mac/arm64 Windows 11 Leaked Semaphores Running Threaded Python Project

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, apple-m1, customtkinter

I'm working on a Python project using scamp to loop audio and customtkinter to display a GUI for customizing the audio but I can't get the project to run on my M1 Mac or arm64 Windows 11. Because the code for the actual project is pretty long I made a small version with the same structure, which I pasted below. I keep getting a leaked semaphore NSInternalInconsistencyException, here's the full error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow should only be instantiated on the main thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d2b48c0 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018cdadeb4 objc_exception_throw + 60
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018d2d9bac _CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey + 0
        3   AppKit                              0x0000000190a29874 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 188
        4   AppKit                              0x0000000190a297ac -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 48
        5   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010bff71a0 TkMacOSXMakeRealWindowExist + 508
        6   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010bff6e90 TkWmMapWindow + 56
        7   libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010bf69f50 MapFrame + 76
        8   libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x000000010c17c7fc TclServiceIdle + 84
        9   libtcl8.6.dylib                     0x000000010c160ae4 Tcl_DoOneEvent + 296
        10  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010bfeadf4 TkpInit + 712
        11  libtk8.6.dylib                      0x000000010bf62f74 Initialize + 2284
        12  _tkinter.cpython-311-darwin.so      0x00000001054e234c Tcl_AppInit + 80
        13  _tkinter.cpython-311-darwin.so      0x00000001054dc8a4 Tkapp_New + 592
        14  _tkinter.cpython-311-darwin.so      0x00000001054dc28c _tkinter_create + 608
        15  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x00000001039af7d8 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL + 260
        16  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x000000010396526c PyObject_Vectorcall + 80
        17  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a455d8 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 35160
        18  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a3cbe0 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        19  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a47100 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42112
        20  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a3cbe0 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        21  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103964be8 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 272
        22  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103965938 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 160
        23  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x00000001039d2168 slot_tp_init + 188
        24  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x00000001039c7c64 type_call + 424
        25  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103964dd0 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 344
        26  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a455d8 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 35160
        27  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a3cbe0 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        28  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a47100 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42112
        29  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a3cbe0 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        30  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a47100 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42112
        31  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a3cbe0 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        32  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a47100 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 42112
        33  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a3cbe0 _PyEval_Vector + 200
        34  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x00000001039678d8 method_vectorcall + 316
        35  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103afb19c thread_run + 108
        36  libpython3.11.dylib                 0x0000000103a9ea30 pythread_wrapper + 28
        37  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018d163034 _pthread_start + 136
        38  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000018d15de3c thread_start + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
zsh: abort      /Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/bin/python3.11 
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:254: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 2 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown                
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
```

I've been developing it on a 64 bit Windows 10 machine but want it to work on my Mac as well. Here's my code:

```
from scamp import Session, fork_unsynchronized
from customtkinter import CTk, CTkLabel
from os import name
from os.path import dirname, abspath
from sys import argv


class LoopingAudio:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.note = 60
        self.session = Session(tempo=100)
        self.instrument = self.session.new_part("instrument", soundfont=dirname(abspath(argv[0])) + "/font.sf2")

    def looper(self):
        while True:
            self.instrument.play_note(self.note, 1, 2)


class LoopingGUI(CTk):
    def __init__(self, looper):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("looper")
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.app_name = CTkLabel(self, text="looper")
        self.app_name.pack()


def start_looper_app():
    looper_engine = LoopingAudio()

    def run_gui():
        looper_gui = LoopingGUI(looper_engine)
        looper_gui.mainloop()
    
    fork_unsynchronized(run_gui)
    looper_engine.looper()


start_looper_app()
```

I googled like crazy trying different methods but I just can't seem to get it to work. I tried using threading instead of scamp's fork_unsynchronized but I get the same error message. I also tried running `start_looper_app` under `if __name__ == "__main__":` but that didn't work either.

I don't know very much about multiprocessing or properly structuring my code so I could just be missing something obvious.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you put all of the stuff that it's `tkinter` related in another thread and keep the main thread for `tkinter`?

Comment: This nearly works but that ends up giving me problems with `scamp`: `WARNING:root:Ran out of threads in the master clock's ThreadPool; small thread creation delays may result. You can increase the number of threads in the pool to avoid this.`

Comment: It's definitely a problem with the `while True` statement causing the script to start a ton of threads. I can check if the `looper_engine.looper` is playing a note with `if looper_engine.looper` and changing `looper_engine.looper` to `self.instrument.play_note(self.note, 1, 2, blocking=True)` but it looks like there's no way to get it to start one thread at a time.